# How to delete/not save files when Jupyter notebook in ran with plotly pio.renderers.default = "iframe"?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-python

I am plotting a plot using plotly python (inside jupyter notebook) like below-

```py
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1, vertical_spacing=0.00)

fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=data.index,
                y=data.col_name,
                name="col_name",
                line=dict(color="#90EE90"),
            ),
            row=1,
            col=1,
        )

fig.show()
```

and I have imported and setup plotly like below

```py
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Notebook setup
pyo.init_notebook_mode()
pio.renderers.default = "iframe"
```

Without `pio.renderers.default = "iframe"` jupyter notebook does not even render the plot.  By using `iframe` I can render the plot, but it starts saving every plot as HTML file with average of 3-4 MB in size on my local machine. How can I avoid that? Is there any better way to render plotly charts which will spare me all other things to deal with?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use `pio.renderers.default = "iframe" ` in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Jupyter notebook can ot seem yo render a plotly plot without using it on my machine. It just shows a black area equal to plot size defined but not the actual plot. From the answers on the internet, I used this line and plots started to show up.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these into the import section:

```
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
pio.renderers
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but its not working for me!

Comment: I updated the answer, I've accidentally omitted a lign in the answer before and restart the Kernal  before running your notebook again.

Comment: I tried this solution with jupyter notebook and jupyter-lab both. It's working with jupyter-lab but `not with the notebook`! Maybe I am missing some dependencies or something. Can you recall about such dependencies? That would be helpful! Thanks :)